# Jquery remove spaces in text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code where I am getting certain text from a string, but I want the output to have no spaces. I have tried putting `.replace(' ', '');` I certain parts of the code but it always stops the code from running

Here is the code im using below, it will output `this text` but I want it to output `thistext`

```
<div id="text"></div>

var text ='blah blah text-name="this text"';

const gettext = text;
const gettextoutput = [];
const re = /text-name="([^"]+)"/g;
let match;
while ((match = re.exec(gettext)) !== null) {
  gettextoutput.push(match[1]);

}

$("#text").append(gettextoutput);
```

Comment: Where have you tried putting the replace?

Comment: basically everywhere, the code stops running when i add it

Comment: Have you checked out my answer? I think I know what the problem with your code was

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning  the matches to an array, you have to replace the spaces of all elements of that array, otherwise JavaScript will throw an error since Arrays don't have a `replace` method.

```js
var text ='blah blah text-name="this text"';

const gettext = text;
const gettextoutput = [];
const re = /text-name="([^"]+)"/g;
let match;
while ((match = re.exec(gettext)) !== null) {
  gettextoutput.push(match[1]);

}

$("#text").append(gettextoutput.map(e => e.replace(" ", "")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, you can do it using vanilla javascript:

`'text with spaces'.split(' ').join('')`

Also, your initial code was on the right way. Try this:

`'text with spaces'.replace(/\s/g, '')`